# Adding pdo-mysql extension to existing container

Tags: php, mysql, docker, pdo

**EDIT:** For anyone trying to get a PHP container with extensions, I found the best solution was to use a [script to install the extensions.](https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer) Works like a charm.

Here is the specific dockerfile I used:

```
FROM php:8.1.0RC3-apache-buster

ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && \
    install-php-extensions sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv pdo_mysql
```

I have an existing container with SQL server extensions installed, so I'm trying to create a new container from that. Here is the docker-compose:

```
    version: '3.1'

services:
  MageAPIDev:
    container_name: MageAPIDev
    image: mc_test:v2
    ports:
      - 200:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html/
      - .app:/var/app/
    command: apt-get install autoconf -y
    command: docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
  MageAPIsql:
    container_name: MageAPIsql
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'PWD'
      MYSQL_USER: 'USER'
      MYSQL_PASS: 'PWD'
  composer:
    image: composer/composer
    command: install
    command: composer require experius/magento2apiclient
    volumes:
      - .app:/app
```

Trying this resulted in:

```
Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
MageAPIDev    | $PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.
```

So I tried bashing into the container and manually installing autoconf. That worked, but when I try to manually install MySQL with `docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql` I get:

```
creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
configure: patching config.h.in
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
/usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-install: 107: /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-install: make: not found
```

I *really* don't want to start the container from scratch. Tbh, I've lost the dockerfile form which I made it, and this has the MSsqlsrv drivers I need. I'm just trying to install and enable the PDO drivers for MySql.

If anyone has an already made dockerfile for PHP 8 with apache that installs SqlSrv drivers and the PDO for MySql, I'll give that a try.

Comment: You might just need an `apt-get update` before the install. I'd look a `docker inspect MageAPIsql` as it will maybe contain enough of the history to re-create the Dockerfile.

Comment: @danblack, I think you misunderstand. The PDO driver for MS Sqlsrv are on MageAPIDev. They were installed with a very lengthy dockerfile I found because installing the drivers is a hassle. I did an inspect on it, and it didn't reveal a whole lot about the original dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying to get a PHP container with extensions, I found the best solution was to use [a script to install the extensions.](https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer) Works like a charm.

Here is the specific dockerfile I used:

```
FROM php:8.1.0RC3-apache-buster

ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && \
    install-php-extensions sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv pdo_mysql
```